# Ubuntu won't boot after install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, 15.04

I have a Windows 10 computer. Whenever I install Ubuntu – tried all methods of installation – after installation Windows 10 boots but Ubuntu won't. I haven't even seen the Select OS menu screen.

Comment: I this for Ubuntu 15.04 or 16.04 (or other)?

Comment: Did you boot the install disk as Legacy or UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

Many new systems come with a newer "bootloader protection" setup so that Windows 10 will automatically run it's bootloader in an effort to stop malware and piracy. You usually have to disable this by entering the BIOS screen and either disabling "Secure Boot" or enabling "Legacy Boot" or disabling "UEFI". The terminology used differs between vendors and BIOS screens.

Some devices require you hold a button during startup for extra security, see your device documentation from the manufacturer if it's non obvious in your BIOS.

Comment: Note that disabling Secure Boot (which is an UEFI feature) is distinct from disabled UEFI altogether (which is also called "enabling Legacy Boot").

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit confusing and it also depends on if Linux is trying to do UEFI. It sounds to me like OP wants to use Legacy boot and disable UEFI all together.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Disabling UEFI is a bit like `chmod 777` to me: it works, but it may not be the best solution for the long term. I think OP should first try have a pure UEFI boot with Secure Boot disabled. If that does not work, then try to disable UEFI.

Comment: I agree it's just I don't think the state of UEFI secure boot signatures for Linux is very good, it was mostly made by Microsoft and the pre-loaded signatures by manufacturers is usually just Microsoft.